Conditional mapping in Pyspark
I have a PySpark DataFrame with 2M rows called inventory with the following columns:



category_id
sub_category_id
product_code
product_name




1001
A001
X123
Gadget A


1001
A002
X456
Gadget B


2002
B003
Y123
Gadget C


3003
C000
Z123
Gadget D


3003
C002
Z456
Gadget E


3003
C003
Z789
Gadget F



I want to map sub_category_id based on condition dicts in category_id

If category_id is 1001, map:

sub_category_id A001 to M001
sub_category_id A002 to M002
if sub_category_id is not in mapping, do nothing.


If category_id is 2002, map:

sub_category_id B003 to N003
...



Here is the mapping example:

mappings = [
    {
        "conditions": [{"column": "category_id", "values": ["1001"]}],
        "values_mapping": {
            "A001": "M001",
            "A002": "M002"
        }
    },
    {
        "conditions": [{"column": "category_id", "values": ["2002"]}],
        "values_mapping": {
            "B003": "N003"
        }
    },
    {
        "conditions": [{"column": "category_id", "values": ["3003"]}],
        "values_mapping": {
            "C001": "P001",
            "C002": "P002",
            "C003": "P003"
        }
    }
]


I want to implement this systematically in PySpark, using a configuration dictionary to define the conditions and mappings.
I tried using a for loop to filter each condition one by one, apply the mappings, and then union each filtered result. However, the performance was very poor.
How can I achieve this efficiently in PySpark?

This should be able to solve your problem assuming your mappings are as provided, later you can drop or preserve and rename the mapped sub category column
df = inputDF.withColumn("mapped_sub_category_id", F.col("sub_category_id"))

for rule in mappings:
    conditions = rule["conditions"]
    values_mapping = rule["values_mapping"]

    category_condition = F.col(conditions[0]["column"]).isin(conditions[0]["values"])

    for original_value, mapped_value in values_mapping.items():
        df = df.withColumn("mapped_sub_category_id",F.when(category_condition & (F.col("sub_category_id") == original_value), mapped_value).otherwise(F.col("mapped_sub_category_id")))


You can loop through the mappings to generate Spark SQL string and apply it.
whens = []
for mapping in mappings:
    category_id = mapping["conditions"][0]["values"][0]
    for sub_category, sub_category_mapped in mapping["values_mapping"].items():
        whens.append(f"WHEN category_id = '{category_id}' AND sub_category_id = '{sub_category}' THEN '{sub_category_mapped}'")

when_str = (' ').join(whens)

case_str = f"""
CASE 
    {when_str}
    ELSE sub_category_id
END AS sub_category_id_mapped
"""

df1 = df.selectExpr("*",  case_str)

